# Flutter TextOverflow.ellipsis - unwanted char at the end of the String

Tags: flutter, dart, text, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I want to use `TextOverflow.ellipsis` on my Flutter web project, however at the end of the String I am getting unwanted char []. I am not sure what is the problem.
Here is a code snippet:

```
Container(
          width: (size.width / 2) - 20,
          height: 260,
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(18)),
              color: Colors.white),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                  topLeft: Radius.circular(18),
                  topRight: Radius.circular(18),
                ),
                child: widget.coverPhoto == null ||
                        widget.coverPhoto.the320X240 == null
                    ? SizedBox(
                        width: (size.width / 2),
                        height: 180,
                        child: const Icon(
                          Icons.no_photography_rounded,
                          size: 35,
                          color: Color.fromRGBO(24, 56, 83, 1),
                        ))
                    : Image.network(
                        widget.coverPhoto.the320X240,
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        width: (size.width / 2),
                        height: 180,
                      ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 10),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8),
                child: Text(
                  "This is a sample text for this widget",
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                  maxLines: 1,
                  softWrap: false,
                  style: const TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                    color: Color.fromRGBO(24, 56, 83, 1),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),
              MyIconButton(
                title: "Na mapě",
                icon: Icons.location_pin,
                backgroundColor: const Color.fromRGBO(24, 56, 83, 1),
                textColor: Colors.white,
                verticalPadding: 5,
                horizontalPadding: 10,
                textSize: 13,
                spaceBetween: 10,
                iconSize: 15,
                borderRadius: 11,
                onTap: () {
                  if (widget.geoLat != null && widget.geoLong != null) {
                    if (widget.mobileView) {
                      mobileMapController.move(
                          LatLng(widget.geoLat!, widget.geoLong!), 17);
                      myMapController.showMap.value = true;
                    } else {
                      desktopMapController.move(
                          LatLng(widget.geoLat!, widget.geoLong!), 17);
                    }
                  }
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
```

UI output:
[image]

Comment: Can you tell me what happens to the string in `widget.name`?? Please tell me the string in which the current character appears

Comment: Hi, yes you are right, sorry about that,  I've updated the code and picture, to make it clearer.

Comment: Everything is working properly on chrome

Comment: I am using chrome as well to debug my code, but so far no luck, issue still persists.

Answer (score 0):

Use `softWrap: false`

```dart
Text(
  widget.name,
  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
  maxLines: 1,
  softWrap: false,
  style: const TextStyle(
    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
    color: Color.fromRGBO(24, 56, 83, 1),
  ),
),
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply, unfortunately it does not solve the issue.

Comment: Are you using `Column` at top level widget, Can you include more about this card that will reproduce the issue? Try with `flutter clean` and build the app.

Comment: Sure, I've added the whole code for the container

Comment: this doesn't help

Comment: @AhmadKhan depends on your widget tree